# Execute requests from the scenario in random order [Taurus/JMeter]

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, taurus

I have a pretty big load test scenario for execution that I want to run with Taurus. It has more than 1000 different requests - some of them in loops because I would like them to execute several times.

Now that I have the scenario completed I'm looking for a way to randomise the requests during the execution. For example instead of the Taurus running the tests line by line from the scenario I would like Taurus to execute requests from the scenario in random order.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to JMeter test plan [Random Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller)

> Random Logic Controller acts similarly to the Interleave Controller, except that instead of going in order through its sub-controllers and samplers, it picks one at random at each pass.

You can even set 1 request at a time

> **ignore sub-controller blocks** If checked, the interleave controller will treat sub-controllers like single request elements and only allow one request per controller at a time.